# setting date range filter in saved search formula

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I’m looking for some guidance on how to write date range filter within saved search formula.  For example, below is what I have so far to see sales of certain type, but also need to add date filter so get only sales for this year to date. I understand I can set date filter in filter section, but I also need to add other columns in this report which will display transaction amounts of different types and dates. Thanks in advance for any input.
Formula:
CASE WHEN {transaction.type} = 'Invoice' AND {transaction.custbody1} = 'Direct' THEN {transaction.amount} end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SQL `TO_CHAR` function to return text portions of a date, for comparison with the corresponding text portions of `sysdate`.  In the example you give, that would look like:

```
CASE WHEN {transaction.type} = 'Invoice' 
        AND {transaction.custbody1} = 'Direct' 
        AND TO_CHAR({trandate}, 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')
    THEN {transaction.amount} 
END
```

You can use the same approach with different formats to get almost any date.  You could also use `EXTRACT` to get slightly better performance in some situations.  `EXTRACT` returns a number rather than text.

```
CASE WHEN {transaction.type} = 'Invoice' 
        AND {transaction.custbody1} = 'Direct' 
        AND EXTRACT(YEAR from {trandate}) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)
    THEN {transaction.amount} 
END
```

You may find `TO_CHAR` to be easier to use when you want to combine different parts of a date.  E.G.: `TO_CHAR({trandate}, 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM')` rather than `EXTRACT(YEAR from {trandate}) = EXTRACT(YEAR from sysdate) AND EXTRACT(MONTH from {trandate}) = EXTRACT(MONTH from sysdate)`